# Eclipse: cannot generate javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I get the following error when generating javadoc:

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main
```

What does it mean?

Thanks, Indeed ItIs

Comment: Are you running eclipse in a JRE?

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason could be you forgot to add the location of your `.class` file to your classpath.

**Solution:-** Add  the location of your `.class` file to your classpath. and if if its in the current folder then add `.` to your classpath.

Also check this [related forum](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2350863?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

javadoc usage is something like

```
javadoc [ options ] [ packagenames ] [ sourcefilenames ] 
[ -subpackages pkg1:pkg2:... ] [ @argfiles ]
```

Even Eclipse does the same thing behind the scenes.You must ensure that you add the location of your .class file to your classpath. So, if its in the current folder then add . to your classpath.

So in Eclipse add the location of your compiled classes to the class path. Or from command line you can use `-cp .` option.

Also check what JRE/JDK is your Eclipse project configured to use. If not configured configure it forst and then try agin.